# Access Android device from Remote computer

Tags: android

Requirement for my implementation is as follows : I want to connect to Android Devices from Remote computer.

This remote computer:

- should be able to control the camera of Android device like Computer
- should be able to take photograph on Device
- should be able to Switch on/off the device camera.

Is there any tutorial or sample code which I can refer for this Implementation?

It would be of great help to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download a vnc client on your pc (such as UltraVNC or TightVNC) and a vnc server on your android device.
As vnc server, try alpha vnc lite from the Play Store. It doesn’t require root and works on almost all Android devices out of the box.

Answer (score -2):

There are a lot of apps that do similar things. I think you should use something like an IP cam functionality to implement such a thing. Just search for some open source projects.

Comment: Yup..I know that many apps available.But you can say I want to implement those apps i.e I want to do this programmatically.

Comment: Look at the second part of my answer.May be you can find some open source projects.